# 7za scheduler problem win2008 server standard edition

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, 7zip

I want to archive in 3 a.m catalog.

I write batch, which works fine:

> 7za a -t7z C:/BackUp/wwwroot/EBC/ebc_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.7z C:/inetpub/wwwroot/EBC/*.* -r

When i do from this scheduler doesn't work.
I have windows server 2008. I add action - choose program - 7za.exe and add optional argument

> a -t7z C:/BackUp/wwwroot/EBC/ebc_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.7z C:/inetpub/wwwroot/EBC/*.* -r

but that task returns code 2

What i am doing wrong??

Regards

Comment: Belongs on superuser or serverfault?

Comment: I do task as administrator - the task starts correctly, first part of this task working fine (first part - backupData base using ExpressMaint.exe)

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution.

I create a batch:

> C:\BackUp\wwwroot\7za.exe a -t7z C:\BackUp\wwwroot\EBC\ebc_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.7z C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EBC*.* -r

And i run a batch and it's works fine.

I don't know why doesn't works my first solutions but now other solution works fine.

Regards